# Different background-images in a menu

Tags: html, css, background-image, menuitem

I have this situation  http://jsfiddle.net/Qy2T2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="margin-top:-5px;">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="box1" style="width:311px; float:left;">
            <div class="markermenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.markermenu{
width: 311px; /*width of menu*/
}

.markermenu ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 1px 0;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #9A9A9A;
}

.markermenu ul li a{
background:url(http://arms.aora.tv/images/cancel-button.jpg) no-repeat 2px center;
height:79px;
color: #00014e;
display: block;
width: auto;
padding: 30px 0;
padding-left: 90px;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B5B5;
}

* html .markermenu ul li a{ 
width: 150px;
}

.markermenu ul li a:visited, .markermenu ul li a:active{
color: #00014e;
}

.markermenu ul li a:hover{
color: black;
background-color: #ffffcb;
background-image:url(http://www.hdc.uk.com/images/med_tick_button.jpg); 
z-index:10;/*onMouseover image change. Remove if none*/
}
```

I need to have different images on the LEFT for every menu voices.
Also i need to put some another images(an arrow) like background (and hover) on the RIGHT of the menu voices.

Is it possible?
Thanks so much

Comment: check i have i updated your fiddle  i hope you want something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ym6sy/

Comment: Mh no. I need that change the images (cancel/V) not the background-color. 
Every voice of the menu must have a different couples of images

Comment: i have gave you sample you can change the background-image property as well

Comment: Have you reason. Thanks so much man

Comment: have you got how you can do that?

Comment: dor changing image you need to change background-image property just

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but from what I understand you could create an additional span within the anchor tag and target it on hover:

```
<a href="#">One
  <span class="altImage"></span>
</a>
```

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/YNd9R/1/

There are ways to simplify the JavaScript/Jquery. I have only provided this as a sample.